# Python/Django: Get record from DB based on a dictionary field

Tags: python, database, dictionary, django-models

I have a database table and **one of the fields** is a serialized python dictionary (or stringified JSON) in this form:
`{"full_name":"first_name=John&last_name=Smith", "id":24354,"username":"hello"}`

How can i select a record based on this field and specifically on the dictionary's username, if i'm searching for a specific username? I mean is there any smart/fast way to do it without loops or splitting the process, maybe with just one line of code?

```
#If the field name is "user_info"
account = theModel.filter(user_info=???)
```

*I know that this design is not so good but i found it that way...

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could use the regex query syntax for Django.

theModel.objects.get(user_info__regex=r'some regex here')

Comment: theModel.objects.get(user_info__iregex=r'"username":"\w+"')

This does not scale well though, it requires a full table scan.  If this field is queried often, it will be much faster if it is a regular Django field: username=CharField(unique=True)